# Android, finish() closes application insead of activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I call an activity for result:

```
private static final int CODE_LOGIN = 0;
private static final int CODE_DETAILS = 1;

private void callDetailsActivity() {
    Intent switchToDetailsActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Details.class);
    switchToDetailsActivity.putExtra(TAG_ID, details.get(TAG_ID));
    startActivityForResult(switchToDetailsActivity, CODE_DETAILS);
}
```

Now in my **Details.class** i call to get back to the previous activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And then my `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CODE_LOGIN) {
                // This is for my other Activity, where the "return" works
        }
    }
    updateOffers();
}
```

But insead of going back to my previous class the application is closed without any error logs. When I press the home button to go to my previous application, I can go to my application and then I am in my previous activity, but thats definately not the way it is supposed to work.

I also tried not to change `onBackPressed()`, or simply write `finish()` into `onBackPressed()`, but nothing worked.

I haven't set `android:noHistory="true"`

With my other Activity (which uses excatly the same code), it works perfectly (CODE_LOGIN).

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you also share the code for your "onActivityResult" in the first activity?

Comment: try to add super.onBackPressed in bottom of onBackPressed() and remove parameters from new Intent().

Comment: Are you calling `finish()` after `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: No, just what it is up there, I updated the code ;)

Comment: What is the value of the constant `CODE_DETAILS`?

Comment: Might be late answer: possibly check whether activity contains launchmode as Singleinstance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `setResult(RESULT_OK, returnToOffers);` to `setResult(RESULT_OK);` and get rid of the returnToOffers intent. I also recommend replacing `finish()` with `super.onBackPressed()` for future compatibility.

Like if in Android Lik-M-Aid (or whatever the next version is), they decide to do some special red glow effect when a user cancels an activity with the back button, you won't have to update your app to support it.

Comment: I have changed the code like you said, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add your manifest to the question and point out which activity isn't working correctly? The problem might be in there.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have declared the first activity as android:noHistory="true" in AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 2):

I found my mistake.
Somewhere deep in my code I accidentally called finish(), so in global I called finish() twice, which leads to closing the application.

Thanks for you help and the advice to use super.onBackPressed()